# Problems with XSLTProcessor

Tags: php, xslt

I have wrote the following code in PHP:

```
 # LOAD XML FILE
$logs = new DOMDocument(); 
$logs->load('dbml.xml');

# START XSLT
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$XSL = new DOMDocument();
$XSL->load( 'dbml.xsl', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL );
#PRINT

$string = $xslt->transformToXML( $logs );
```

The code works perfectly,however some strange warnings appear on my browser.

```
Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet() [xsltprocessor.importstylesheet]: compilation error: file file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/PHP/Escola_Musica/dbml.xsl line 5 element stylesheet in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Escola_Musica\teste.php on line 13

Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet() [xsltprocessor.importstylesheet]: xsl:version: only 1.0 features are supported in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Escola_Musica\teste.php on line 13
```

Did anyone here have the same problem, and was able to fix it. I would appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The problem is in your dbml.xsl so without code how should we find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to load an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet with a processor that only supports 1.0.